# Get length of input type password with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the password's length so I prevent form submition if it's too short. How is this done?

This is what I'm trying right now:

```
$('#registerForm input[type="password"]').val.length
```

Comment: Try using the jQuery `.val()` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`val` is a function, so you need to write `val()`:

```
$('#registerForm input[type="password"]').val().length
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add an id `<input id="pw" type="password">`

```
$('#pw').val().length;
```

**or** You can add a class `<input class="pw" type="password">`

```
$('.pw').val().length;
```

**else** keep it as it is and you can get the length using jquery

```
$('#registerForm input[type="password"]').val().length;
```

Hope this will help you out. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to evalute `val` as a function.

```
$('#registerForm input[type="password"]').val().length
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `$('#txtbox').val().length;` to get the length

**[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cGxs/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use this  you have some error in your code

```
$('#registerForm input[type="password"]').val().length
```